# Accessing variable from outside class definition?

Tags: php, wordpress, scope, procedural-programming

I am new to PHP, and whatever little I know is the "functional programming" side of it. I am using a plugin that appears to follow the "object oriented programming" style, and would like to access a variable for use within my own function. I don't know how to do it.

To give you an idea, this is what the class definition in the plugin looks like (kind of):

```
<?php

    class WPSEO_Frontend {
        public function canonical() {
            $canonical = get_page_link();
        }
    }
?>
```

And this how another file in the plugin calls the variable `$canonical`:

```
<?php
    class WPSEO_Twitter extends WPSEO_Frontend {
        public function twitter_url() {
            echo '<meta name="twitter:url" content="' . esc_url( $this->canonical() ) . '"/>' . "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Now, I want to be able to access `$canonical` variable (in functional programming style) in my function, in a different file. For example, like this:

```
<?php
    function seo_meta_tags() {
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . $canonical . '">' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

How do I do that? Is it possible?

***PS:** Given my knowledge I don't know if I am missing anything, so please do let me know.*

Comment: Maybe try `WPSEO_Frontend::canonical()`

Comment: @TheHumbleRat I get this error: ***Strict Standards:** Non-static method WPSEO_Frontend::canonical() should not be called statically*

Comment: Yeah it's not a static method, or it would say static in the definition.

Comment: You could change `public function actionPurchaseOrderNumberS1($pp_purordnum)` to this `public static function actionPurchaseOrderNumberS1($pp_purordnum)`. But you may be better off with the other answers, I am still new to this myself.

Comment: No, you should not be editing a plugin's code directly, especially if you don't know OOP, and I have no idea where @TheHumbleRat got that function name...

Comment: @Jessica point taken regarding editing plugin code. The function name is from an example of fixing the error "Strict Standards: Non-static method". Anyway I'll leave this question to the pros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Your `WPSEO_Frontend::canonical` function should return a value so that when other parts of your code calls the function a value instead of void is returned.
2. Since `canonical` is a member function of `WPSEO_Frontend` you need to have an instance of `WPSEO_Frontend` to call the `canonical` function.

Update `WPSEO_Frontend::canonical` function to return `get_page_link()`:

```
<?php

    class WPSEO_Frontend {
        public function canonical() {
            return get_page_link();
        }
    }
?>
```

Then in your `seo_meta_tags` function use an instance of `WPSEO_Frontend` to call `canonical`:

```
<?php
    function seo_meta_tags() {
        $wp_seo_frontend = new WPSEO_Frontend();
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . $wp_seo_frontend->canonical() . '">' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Comment: this answer doesn't answer the question

Comment: @link, I believe I was adding required code change when you posted your comment.  Anyway thanks for that and any other feedback appreciated.

Comment: @vee Worked like a charm, thank you very much for the clear example.

Comment: @vee There seems to be a small problem. With `$wp_seo_frontend = new WPSEO_Frontend();` added within my function, the plugin's original output is shown two times. (Whatever my code is meant for, it working fine. The plugin itself is messed up due to that line.) Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind. `WPSEO_Frontend()` is already instantiated by the plugin and available as a global variable `$wpseo_front` Now, I can simply use it like this `$wpseo_front->canonical( false )`. https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/master/frontend/class-frontend.php#L1428.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have an instance of the WPSEO_Frontend class (or the class that extends it).  I'll call it `$instance`. You would then pass that variable into your function.

I'm assuming that first function either returns the value, or set it to a property using the $this keyword.

The WPSEO_Frontend class may have a getter function for that property, so you may need to do

```
$instance->getCanonical();
```

Or just

```
$instance->canonical;
```

Without seeing more of the actual code we can't tell you much more than that. If the function `canonical()` actually returns something, that is the function to call.

Comment: If you can take a look, it's an open source plugin. The first code block in my question: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/master/frontend/class-frontend.php#L631 and here's the second: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/master/frontend/class-twitter.php#L146

Comment: So, yes, it does return something, so you can call canonical(); In the code where you execute your seo_meta_tags function, do you already have an instance of that other class?

Comment: No, I don't. I created one as shown in @vee's answer, and it worked! Thanks you very much for your time. (**EDIT:** Didn't see your edited comment.)

Comment: Any idea how I can create an instance without messing with the plugin? With `$wp_seo_frontend = new WPSEO_Frontend();` added within my function, the plugin's original output is shown two times. (Whatever my code is meant for, it working fine. The plugin itself is messed up due to that line.)

Comment: That means somewhere in your code the plugin has already been `instantiated` (the new line `$wp_seo_frontend = new WPSEO_Frontend();` exists somewhere else). It's really hard to say without seeing the code but I would search your codebase for `new WPSEO_Frontend();` and see if you can use the same variable it's already using, pass it into your function.

Comment: Ah, you are so right. There's a global variable `$wpseo_front` defined in the plugin itself! Now, I can simply use it. https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/master/frontend/class-frontend.php#L1428. Can't thank you enough.